# What's the role of spring boot cache annotations in a application which use Redis for caching?

Tags: java, spring, caching, redis, spring-data-redis

I am using Redis as the in-memory data store for caching purposes in my spring boot application. At the moment I have already implemented the Redis support with basic CRUD functionalities for the entities which I need to cache [Scenario 1] . But suddenly I found that there are lots of resources out there that use additional spring boot caching annotations like `@Cachable @CahceEvict` to implement the caching with Redis [Scenario 2] . And I monitored that when we start using those annotations in an operation like find(params) only the first method call will be going to the Redis. From the second method onwards, Redis won't get hit. So according to my observations, I think, Spring boot maintains a separate cache. But my problem is we are already using Redis as our cache. So what's the advantage of stopping the second Redis data store hit and maintaining another cache. I mean Redis is already in the RAM and it's highly capable of caching. Why do we need to maintain two caches? Is there any advantage of having this mechanism or does implement the Redis only is enough ?.

**Scenario 1 :**

```
public class RestController{

@GetMapping("/{id}")
public Product findProductById(@PathVariable int Id){
           return dao.findProductById(id);
}


}
```

```
@Repository
public class ProductDao {

    public static final String HASH_KEY = "Product";

    @Autowired
    private RedisTemplate template;
  

    public Product findProductById(int id){
        return (Product) template.opsForHash().get(HASH_KEY,id);
    }

}
```

**Scenario 2 :**

```
public class RestController{

@GetMapping("/{id}")
@Cachable(key = "#id" ,value="Product")
public Product findProductById(@PathVariable int Id){
           return dao.findProductById(id);
}

}
```

```
@Repository
public class ProductDao {

    public static final String HASH_KEY = "Product";

    @Autowired
    private RedisTemplate template;
  

    public Product findProductById(int id){
        System.out.println("called findProductById() from DB");//Here only for the first time method will be called
        return (Product) template.opsForHash().get(HASH_KEY,id);
    }

}
```

[References for Scenario 1 implementation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oRGqCz8OLcM&t=123s)

[References for Scenario 2 implementation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vpe4aDu5ixI)

Comment: Suppose the code dealt with caching directly - that would require every method that was involved in caching to be aware of, and use some (hopefully injected) dependency.  That's possible, but is a lot of noise and probably at least some duplicate code.  Every unit test would require additional setup, which provides no business value (maybe there is non-functional value for such a test).  The annotations abstract away the cache implementation so once the cache provider is configured you're done. But do consider adding some integration tests to verify the cache is working.

Comment: @Andrew S Actually I am not sure whether you understood my question correctly. I mean think you are implementing your redis repository (Data access layer)  and you are calling for an example a method call findById(params) , I saw in a video when you use Cachable annotation only the first time data will retrieve from the actual redis data store. But from the second call actually the findById(params) won't get triggered. Because spring will cache the value in some where else and hand it over. So I am asking why do we need such a mechanism. Because we are already using Redis as the cache.

Comment: Please have a look on references.

Answer (score 4):

The [Spring Cache abstraction](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/integration.html#cache) provides a cache abstraction layer you can configure to support different, pluggable, underlying cache mechanisms, [Redis through Spring Data](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-redis/docs/current/reference/html/#redis:support:cache-abstraction) among others.

You are using Redis as the actual persistence mechanism. As a consequence, probably you do not need any cache and, due to the in-memory nature of the Redis database, the scenario 1 can be appropriate.

Having said that, please, consider a different point of view.

Let's consider for example a backend that uses a persistence layer with an underlying *not in-memory* database, relational or other flavor of NoSQL.

This is a perfect use case for Spring Cache, `@Cacheable` and the rest of related annotations to effectively cache your results.

And, how Redis fits in to this puzzle? Because you [configure Spring](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-redis/docs/current/reference/html/#redis:support:cache-abstraction) to use Redis as the actual [cache manager](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-redis/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/redis/cache/RedisCacheManager.html). For example:

```java
@Bean
public RedisCacheManager cacheManager(RedisConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
    return RedisCacheManager.create(connectionFactory);
}
```

Under the hood `RedisCacheManager` will provide the necessary mechanisms to transparently write and read from Redis as required by the application cache.

With this new point of view, the scenario 2, with the above-mentioned differences, is the one to choose and in fact is a common scenario you usually find when architecting enterprise applications.

In any case, the scenario 2 as described in your question, I mean, using Redis directly as the persistence mechanism in addition to Spring Cache, can be also applicable if you are trying:

- Reducing the number of requests - and associated costs - performed against Redis. This could be relevant especially if you are using Redis (or a Redis-like service such as GCP Memorystore) in a cloud provider.
- Despite the fact that Redis is fast enough, you can use a cache to store the results in the local RAM of the machine running your application to improve performance, just like with any other database system.
- Or because you need to interact with Redis in some specific way.

If you are using Redis only for caching and do not require any specific stuff, probably it would be preferable to use it through the Spring Cache abstraction instead of manually perform the cache operations: it will provide no performance benefit, but you will get a several advantages like a well structured cache framework, with a set of helpful annotations, and portability/usability because you can switch the cache implementation only using a different configuration if required, for testing or local development, for example.

Comment: I am 100 percent agree to use this with a scenario like , in a case to cache data in a storage which use HDD .But what I am asking is according to this scenario what is the advantage that we can obtain by following this approach.I mean I have seen the second scenario of implementing Redis with Spring caching annotations in many other places on the internet.So why then they all share these kind of incorrect confusing stuff around the internet.I mean there must be a reason for that.

Comment: I mean at least does the implementation of those annotations drive the application to cache those data in a storage like  L1,L2, or L3. Because then definitely performance will be increase .So according to your explanation from the second method call  , even though we don't see any Redis db hit actually the method is invoking.I mean if  those annotations are also using the Redis as the cache then definitely the data should be fetch as usual from the Redis.

Comment: @HasinduDahanayake I tried providing some additional ideas in the answer. But yes, that is the point, under the hood `RedisCacheManager` will provide the necessary mechanisms to transparently write and read from Redis as required by the cache.

Comment: So just get things clear , So according to you implementing Redis with Spring boot cache abstraction is the right call.I mean according to your explanation as I asked before when it comes to performance both of these scenarios are identical.I mean even though we see Redis may not get hit after the second method call in the second scenario it's actually being hit .(I am referencing the method findProductById()) .So in the second scenario also there are only a single cache storage available which is Redis.

Comment: I mean spring boot won't store the data which is need to return from the second method call upwards in a separate cache storage or any where else like L1, L2 or L3 memory.It's the same storage which is Redis .So I am I correct ?

Comment: You are correct @HasinduDahanayake, Spring Boot will provide no performance benefit, is the sam storage which is Redis. Please, see the updated answer.